# Armazenar vários números em uma variável e depois imprimir e mostrar a soma

Tags: java

Preciso fazer um programa que faça o seguinte :

• Comece com um inteiro N

• Se N é par, divida por 2;

• Se N é ímpar, multiplique por 3 e some 1;

• Repita esse novo processo com o novo valor de N, se N ≠ 1;

• Termina o processo quando N = 1.

```
Scanner NUM = new Scanner(System.in);
double numerox; 
System.out.println("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
double NUM1 = NUM.nextDouble();


    while ((NUM1 % 2 == 0) && (NUM1 != 1))
    {
     numerox = NUM1 * 2;
        System.out.println(+numerox);
        break;
```

Eu só consegui fazer isso.

O que posso fazer para criar uma variável que armazene esses números e depois imprimi-los e mostrar sua soma?

Pensei em criar uma variável `NUMX` mas não sei se vai funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Com a contribuição de Van Ribeiro consegui fazer o que se pede, descartei completamente o modo que eu estava tentando fazer usando array e FOR.

```
    Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite um número:");
    int n = leitor.nextInt();

    final int n2 = n;
    int soma = 0;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Sequência: "+n+" ");

    while(n != 1){

        if(n%2==0){
            n = n/2;
        }else{
            n = (n * 3) + 1;
        }

        System.out.print(n+" ");

        soma += n;

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Soma: "+(n2+soma));

}
```

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! ✌

Answer (score 0):

João, não sei se te ajuda, mas fiz baseado nas instruções que passou na questão:

```
Scanner lendo = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = lendo.nextInt();
int soma = 0;

while(n != 1){
    if(n%2==0){
        n = n/2;
    } else{
        n = (n * 3) + 1;
    }
    soma += n;
}

System.out.println(soma);
```

Pelo o que entendi das suas instruções, você precisa que um `n` seja atualizado sempre que operação é efetuada.

Nesse caso, fiz com que toda vez que uma operação matemática fosse calculada, após obedecer a condição do número ser par ou impar, a própria variável `n` recebesse o resultado dessas operações.

E, a cada vez que o `while` é executado, a variável `soma` é atualizada com resultado de `n`, sendo acrescida sobre ela mesmo, até que `n` seja 1.

Espero que te ajude! Até mais!

Answer (score 0):

Bom amigo, para esse problema eu faria uma variável acumuladora, para somar os resultados da operação.
Então sendo assim:

```
int acum = 0; //variavel acumulador
int N; //variavel a ser lida
```

Após ser feita a leitura, a lógica para o problema seria:

```
while(N!=1){ //Enquanto N for diferente de 1
    if(N%2==0){
        acum += N; //Soma o valor de N ao acumulador
        N /= 2; //Divisao de N/2, seria o mesmo de N = N/2
    }else{
        acum += N;
        N = N*3 + 1;
    }
}
```

Com esse resultado, você teria a soma de todas as variáveis que passaram. Caso queira saber quais foram todas as variáveis que foram somadas, sugiro usar uma pilha para isso.

```
Stack<Integer> pilha = new Stack<>();//variavel acumulador
int N; //variavel a ser lida

while(N!=1){ //Enquanto N for diferente de 1
    if(N%2==0){
        pilha.push(N); //Inserção na Pilha
        N /= 2; //Divisao de N/2, seria o mesmo de N = N/2
    }else{
        pilha.push(N);
        N = N*3 + 1;
    }
}
```

Para exibir a soma da pilha no entanto:

```
int acum = 0;
while(!pilha.empty()){ //enquanto a pilha não for vazia
    acum += pilha.pop();

}

System.out.println("Valor do Acumulador: " + acum);
System.out.println("Valores da Pilha");
for(Integer val : pilha){
    System.out.println("Valor: " + val);

}
```

Espero que tenha ajudado